# Excel INDIRECT fails when sheet name is C2a or C2b

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

Here's a weird problem:
I open a blank Excel 2013 workbook and create 4 new tabs named `A2a`, `B2a`, `C2a` and `D2a`.
I now go back to the `Sheet1` and create a small table with the 4 names in cells `A3:A6` and use the following forumlas:
`B3` gets `=INDIRECT(A3&"!F9")`
`C3` gets `=INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!F9")`
Dragging down these formulas, Sheet `C2a` gives a `#REF!` error in column B when all other sheets do not return an error...

I'm fine with using Column C formulas as they will cover cases where there is a space in the Sheet Name but still, I'd like to understand why I get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen with not just letter `C` but with letter `R` as INDIRECT is designed to handle R1C1 style notations.

So to inform Excel that it is literal C and R you need to pass arguments like C3 formula.

Hope this helps!